# Error: Failed to fetch data client side on Next.js 13.4

Tags: next.js

I'm long time Next.js 12 user and never had an issue with its documentation before,
just tried the new Next.js 13.4 and wanted to add a simple client side api call to my locally hosted strapi with:

**page.js**

```
'use client';

async function getData() {
  try{
    const res = fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/posts`);

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    return res.json();

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await getData()
  console.log(posts)

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-5">
    </main>
  )
}
```

but it throws `Error: Failed to fetch data` .
I obviously tested the `http://localhost:1337/api/posts` url first in browser and it returns the json correctly.
So anyone know what's going on? Next.js documentation says to call the fetch this way.

Comment: @Nathan_Bernard you can check the solution below as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Next.js `13.4`, the default behavior for `fetch` has changed, and it no longer automatically resolves promises.

I modified the code so the function handles the promise:

```js
async function getData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/posts');

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    return res.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

```js
export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const posts = await getData();
      console.log(posts);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I added `useEffect`, so it ensures it runs after the component is executed.

Or this :

```js
async function getData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/posts`);

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    return res.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export default function Home() {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const posts = await getData();
    console.log(posts);
  };

  fetchData();

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-5">
      {/* Add your JSX content here */}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: now throws: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 1337
  }
}

Comment: Updated it added useeffect

Comment: now the error is logged frontend instead, nothing changes, Error: Failed to fetch data

Comment: i forgot to removed the await res.json you dont need that. i updated the code

Comment: same thing this is weird

Comment: Maybe its something with CORS?

Comment: no sorry it works now, it was that between the hundred tests I added the authorization bearer header to the request, removed that it now console.log correctly frontend. thank you

Comment: Hi @VåldeMort! You said *"and it no longer automatically resolves promises"*, which is not correct. `fetch` never resolved a promise by itself.

Comment: I noticed that all this shouldn't be working with useEffect anyway since I'm using the 'use client' at the top of the page, in fact if i console.log something inside the page (but outside the useEffect) it logs server side instead of client side, erroneously, since 'use client' should make the page a client side component

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use client';

async function getData() {
    const res = fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/posts`);

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    const data = await res.json()

    return data; // Add await to res.json()
  }
}

export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await getData()

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-5">
    </main>
  )
}
```

Try awaiting `res.json()` before returning the result. This should work properly as I faced same issue lately.